# Installation of opencv and ffmpeg on anaconda

Tags: opencv, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, deep-learning, anaconda

I am using an amazon EC2 instance and working on a deep learning problem. I want to install opencv along with ffmpeg on anaconda python in order to process the video frames. Can somebody please help out with the installation?

Comment: I installed both opencv and ffmpeg separately on anaconda but it didnt work for me. I havent been able to find any solution that could help in enabling the use of ffmpeg in opencv on anaconda

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to import opencv?

Comment: The opencv is imported fine, but my code is not able to extract the frames from the video files because opencv is not able to use ffmpeg

Comment: Can you post your code and the output that you are getting?

Comment: I installed `ffmpeg` in OpenCV on Anaconda for my Windows system using  [THIS LINK](http://kronoskoders.logdown.com/posts/256664-installing-opencv-and-ffmpeg-on-windows) . See if it works for you. There is no guarantee.

Comment: I am working on ubuntu and followed these links for installation of opencv and ffmpeg: https://anaconda.org/phhuang/opencv https://anaconda.org/menpo/ffmpeg but so far I have not been successful

Comment: @shawshank     i am following this code http://learnandshare645.blogspot.in/2016/06/3d-cnn-in-keras-action-recognition.html

Comment: Frames per second using video.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS): 0.0
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.area() > 0) in resize, file -------src-dir-------/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 1968
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 44, in <module>
    frame=cv2.resize(frame,(img_rows,img_cols),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.error: -------src-dir-------/opencv-2.4.10/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:1968: error: (-215) ssize.area() > 0 in function resize     @shawshank this is the error i get

Comment: hi  i suggest you compile opencv yourself and put the cv2.so in ~/anaconda2/envs/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages, assuming the name of the virtual env is `env`. I gave up on anaconda opencv. Besides, if you want nice qt gui window instead of the gtk one, you can have it too if you compile yourself.

Comment: Did you pip install opencv or conda install opencv ?